# Can't apply WPF theme on the window itself

Tags: wpf, themes

I'm trying to apply the ExpressionDark theme from the [Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Themes) CodePlex project.

I have added the file `ExpressionDark.xaml` in a `Themes` subfolder, and changed my `App.xaml` file to reference this file :

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary
                Source="Themes/ExpressionDark.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

When I run the program, the styles are applied to all controls but not the window itself. The window's background remains white. What I understand is that the style applies to `Window` class, but not to derived class.

To workaround this issue, I've try to create a new style in my `app.xaml` file, in order to inherits the Windows style for my custom window class :

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style
            TargetType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}"
            BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}" />
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary
                Source="Themes/ExpressionDark.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

The result is strictly identical.

I've also try the advise from [WPF: Adventures in Theming (Part 2)](http://www.nickdarnell.com/2010/01/wpf-adventures-in-theming-part-2/). I added to my window definition :

```
<Window
    x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModel"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="350"
    Width="525"
    Style="{DynamicResource {x:Type Window}}" />
```

No more success.

What is missing?

PS: don't know if it matters, but my window's child is a Grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last time i checked there was no `Window` style in the theme.

Comment: Do you have an advise to properly set the window's background color in this case?

Comment: @SteveB: There should be a resource defined in the theme (i think it's `ControlBackgroundBrush`), just directly reference it in the `Background` property (or a style's `Setter`).

Comment: `<Setter
                    Property="Background"
                    Value="{StaticResource ShadeBrush}" />`... Get It! Just wondering why the screenshots on the theme page have a background color defined (there no sample I can explore).

Comment: @SteveB: (Are you sure it's `ShadeBrush` you want to use?) I think there is no style because of the missing inheritance.

Comment: No I'm not sure. I'm new to using theme, I was hoping to dynamically apply a out of the box style, just by referencing it. I'm discovering this is not enough.

Comment: I found `ControlBackgroundBrush`, is it the one you think about?

Comment: @SteveB: Yes. (edited into my comment above somewhere, you apparently missed that edit)

Answer (score 3):

Specify Background using dynamic resource in the Window XAML

```
<Window x:Class="HellowWorld.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Hellow World" Height="614" Width="821"
        Background="{DynamicResource WindowBackgroundBrush}">
```